# Memory Leak when calling NSUserDefaults setObject

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsuserdefaults

I am working through an exercise to store some data in NSUserDefaults.  The data is list of dictionary objects with unique identifying information about each picture.  The list is about 20 elements and the information in the dictionary is a bunch of small strings.  The image itself is certainly not stored.

I have ARC disabled on purpose so I can learn memory management.

I ran the profiler and I experience a memory leak on the line that stores that array back into NSUserDefaults.  Any ideas?

```
+ (void) addPhotoToRecentList:(NSDictionary *)photoInformation
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *photoId = [photoInformation objectForKey:(FLICKR_PHOTO_ID)];

    NSMutableArray *recentPhotoList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:RECENT_PHOTO_LIST]];


    if (!recentPhotoList) {
        recentPhotoList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"recentPhotoList is %@", recentPhotoList);
        NSDictionary *photoElement;
        for (photoElement in recentPhotoList) {
            if ([photoId isEqualToString:[photoElement objectForKey:(FLICKR_PHOTO_ID)]]) {
                [recentPhotoList removeObject:photoElement];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (recentPhotoList.count == MAX_PHOTOS) {
            [recentPhotoList removeLastObject];
        }

    }

    [recentPhotoList insertObject:photoInformation atIndex:0];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:RECENT_PHOTO_LIST];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:recentPhotoList forKey:RECENT_PHOTO_LIST];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Please note I added the following line:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:RECENT_PHOTO_LIST];
```

Wondering if that helps with the memory leak, however it makes not difference.

If I comment out that line:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:recentPhotoList forKey:RECENT_PHOTO_LIST];

Then no more memory leak, but also I don't get to save the list of recently accessed pictures.

Here is what gave away the fact that I have a memory leak, I ran the Profiler with Leaks Instrument.  Also, before I did that I ran the analyzer and had cleaned up all offending issues.  There are no warnings.

Also, and I may be breaking some iOS rule.  I have two separate views that can modify the frequently saved list.  As a short cut, I decided to save that in NSUserDefaults, so if I click on a list of pictures frequently, then I would call to save to NSUserDefaults every time. And if I call the Recently Viewed List controller it would pull that information from NSUserDefaults and update it as well to keep the most recent photos on top.

I am considering making a global class that is reachable by these Views to temporarily save to the list and then when the app goes in background or exits it would call into NSUserDefaults to save, however I would like to understand the source of this memory leak.

[image]

The caller of this function is:

```
- (void) doActualWork
{
    if (!self.selectedPhotoDict) {
        NSLog(@"AMRO No picture selected must be an iPad");
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        return;
    }

    photoData = [[FlickrFetcher imageDataForPhotoWithFlickrInfo:self.selectedPhotoDict format:FlickrFetcherPhotoFormatLarge] retain];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [RecentTableViewController addPhotoToRecentList:self.selectedPhotoDict];

    //With Splitviews this is how we refresh our view
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [self loadPhoto];
    }

}
```

The caller of this is from another view that pushes a photo view controller to load a particular picture.  I run the function in the background to allow me to set the network indicator to busy.

```
- (void)setSelectedPhotoDict:givenSelectedPhotoDict
{
    if (_selectedPhotoDict) {
        [_selectedPhotoDict release];
    }

    _selectedPhotoDict = [givenSelectedPhotoDict retain];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay]; // any time our Model changes, redraw our View
        if (photoData) {
            [photoData release];
        }

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        [self performSelector:@selector(doActualWork) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.01];
    }    
}
```

Comment: Kudos for disabling ARC and forcing yourself to learn memory management. Can you post the screenshot of what the profiler shows (the call graph that leads to a memory leak)? Also, have you tried running the [Leaks Instrument](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/) to see what it has to say?

Comment: Run the Analyzer and click on ant blue points in the code to see the path causing the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem just with the code you've provided. Could you include the code that calls addPhotoToRecentList:?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  Here are some additional pieces of information.  Before I ran the Profiler, I ran the Analyzer and cleaned up all the Blue Points, there are none.

Comment: The profiler with the Leaks Instrument is what told me that I have memory leaks, I will post a screen shot of that soon.  Also, to put things in context.  I have two Table View Controllers, one that lists photos and clicking on a photo adds it to an array of photos that are saved in NSUserDefaults.  The other Table View Controller is the recent photo list that gleans the list from NSUserDefaults.  I was thinking of making a central class to manage the recent list and is accessible to these table view controllers where I would use NSUserDefaults only when my app exits or goes in the background.

Comment: I don't see any leaks in the code posted; look at your other code. Instruments should be able to tell you something more than you have said. Off topic why use NSUserDefaults instead of CoreData for this?

Comment: I would start by looking at properties. how is your `selectedPhotoDict` declared? is it retain or copy?

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the feedback, selectedPhotoDict is declared as such: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *selectedPhotoDict;  
So as a result, in the setter I put up in my question: - (void)setSelectedPhotoDict:givenSelectedPhotoDict
  I modified the line:     _selectedPhotoDict = [givenSelectedPhotoDict retain];
 and removed the retain.  I am going to run the profiler a few times and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Off topic, CoreData is my next set of exercises to cache data.  One baby step at a time I'm still a beginner at this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off thank you Brad Allred for the hint.

What threw me off was that if I disabled the line:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:recentPhotoList forKey:RECENT_PHOTO_LIST];
```

Then the leak went away, but that was addressing the symptom not the root cause.

The method, addPhotoToRecentList() is getting called by the setter method of my NSDictionary:

```
- (void)setSelectedPhotoDict: givenSelectedPhotoDict
```

Per Brad's recommendation, I re-examined the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *selectedPhotoDict;
```

Which got me thinking, in the setter function, I had the line:

```
_selectedPhotoDict = [givenSelectedPhotoDict retain];
```

So I removed the retain:
    _selectedPhotoDict = givenSelectedPhotoDict;

ran Analyze, all was clean, re ran the Profiler several times with the same set of test cases and the leak is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not on your userdefaults but it is on your mutableArray where your are initializing and inserting and removing object. Please check you mutable array objects if it got released then definitely you try to access it will crash